# What is the difference between composition and aggregation in java?

Tags: java, oop, object, aggregation, composition

If I understand correctly composition and aggregation are relationships that objects share.
In composition, the dependent object cannot exist without the parent. Whereas, in aggregation, the dependent objects can exists without a parent. 
The composition is implemented in java by having non-static inner class but aggregation by having a static inner class or object references.
Please correct me if I am wrong. Have browsed through web lot but didn't get satisfying answeres just confusion.

Comment: please can you explain with an example

Comment: Please show what you've looked at. The tutorials online are generally pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

First of all both Composition and Aggregation are part association.
Association means relation exist between classes.

In **Composition** which two entities are highly dependent on each other and the composed object cannot exist without the other entity.

```
class Employee{

}

class Company{
List<Employee> employeeList;
}
```

**Aggregation:**

It is a unidirectional association ( one way relationship)
Both the entries can survive individually which means ending one entity will not effect the other entity

```
//Either girl like boy
class Girl{
 List<Boy> boyList;
}

//Either boy like like
class Boy{
 List<Girl> girlList;
}
```

I'm giving this example because i'm a programmer, you also know that.